# Moving pivot query builder from controller to model scope

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have this working in my controller currently:

```php
use App\Models\Organisation;
use App\Models\User;

public function show(User $user)
{
    $orgs = Organisation::with([
            'users' => function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                      ->orWhereNull('user_id');
            }
        ])
        ->get();

    dd($orgs);
}
```

I would like to move as much as possible to the model using a dynamic local scope. I have tried:

```php
public function scopeAllOrgsOneUserMemberOrNot($query, $user)
{
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->orWhereNull('user_id');
}
```

But when I run:

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    $orgs = Organisation::with(['users' => function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->AllOrgsOneUserMemberOrNot($query, $user);
    }])->get();
    dd($orgs);
}
```

I get back the following ErrorException:
`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$id`

How do I move this query builder snippet to a scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope's first parameter does not need to be passed. Check the example in the documentation. `function scopeActive($query) { ... }` turns into `active()`.

```php
$query->AllOrgsOneUserMemberOrNot($user);
```

This should work.